# How big of a container will I want to grow mushrooms in to keep the environment sterile?

Tags: mushrooms

I'm experimenting with growing black oyster mushrooms, and shiitake mushrooms this summer in plastic boxes to keep the house fungus free. how big of containers would you recommend keeping to grow enough mushrooms for a family of 3?

Comment: But you know that the mushroom cultures won’t be an issue, health-wise whereas mold spores (also fungi) are? Am not too convinced that growing the mushrooms in sealed boxes is a good idea.

Comment: And probably just nitpicking: No matter how diligently you clean your house, it won’t be sterile. Far from it, in fact.

Comment: the mushrooms will take down the house over time and my parents own the house, and i want the mushrooms to be edible not poisonous after opening them up.

Comment: Black oyster mushrooms are definitely not interested in dry and healthy wood. Even if they appear on live trees, they are feeding on already decaying material: it’s a saprophyte, not a parasite. Same for shitake. If your parents’ house has rotting wood, you have a much worse problem to worry about that the unlikely case of a mushroom spore rooting (unlikely anyway, because they don’t use all wood indiscriminately).

Answer (score 2):

for **2-3 mushroom blocks** you need plastic box about **40-80Qt (40-80L), the bigger the better.**
Environment won't be 100% sterile, however it's possible to grow totally healthy mushrooms.

Oysters produce too much CO2, so you need air pump or fan for constant fresh air exchange.

CO2 for oysters and shiitake should be <1,000 ppm for fruiting period, fresh air exchanges at least 4–8 times/day.

Of course high relative humidity (~90-95%) and light requirements about 500–1,000 lux

You can find more details regarding growth parameters for each period of cultivation cycle and for different species in the book by *Paul Stamets "Growing Gourmet and Medicinal Mushrooms"*.

Also **grow tent** (as for plants) would be great for your purpose.

Have a happy growing!